# Question to Corollary on $S$-semipermutable subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Two subgroup $A, B \le G$ are said to *permute* if $AB = BA$. A subgroup $H \le G$ is called $S$-semipermutable in $G$ if $H$ permutes with every *Sylow* $q$-subgroup of $G$ for primes $q$ not dividing $|H|$.

**Theorem:** Let $H$ be an $S$-semipermutable $\pi$-subgroup of $G$. Then $H^G$ contains a nilpotent $\pi$-complement, and all $\pi$-complements in $H^G$ are conjugate. Also, if $\pi$ consists of a single prime, then $H^G$ is solvable.

**Corollary:** If a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ is $S$-semipermutable, then $G$ is $p$-solvable.

*Proof:* Let $P$ be an $S$-semipermutable Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. Then $P^G$ is solvable by the above Theorem. Since $P^G$ is normal and has $p'$-index in $G$, it follows that $G$ is p-solvable. $\square$

Why does $P^G$ normal and $p'$-index implies it is $p$-solvable?

Comment: A $p$-solvable group is one whose composition factors all either order $p$ or order coprime to $p.$ Any normal series can be refined to a composition series. If $N$ is a solvable normal subgroup of $G$ such that $G/N$ is a $p^{\prime}$-group, then the composition factors of $$G$ are those of $G/N,$ together with the composition factors of $N.$ Hence all either have prime order or order prime to the given prime $p.$Hence all composition factors of $G$ all have order $p$ or prime to $p.$